# How to convert Microsoft Graph Explorer's prefer = minimal header into Powershell's Invoke-webrequest?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

How to convert "prefer=minimal" request header if I write a PowerShell code within the  Invoke-Webrequest to minimize the response?

```
$Data = Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $authHeader -Uri $Url -Body $body -Method POST -UseBasicParsing -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8" -prefer "return=minimal"
```

This code does not work from my end.

[PowerShell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94Fr2.png)

Answer (score 0):

[`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6) does not support `Prefer` parameter, it needs to be specified via `Headers` parameter instead, for example:

```
$Url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta?`$select=displayName,jobTitle,mobilePhone"
$headers = @{
    Authorization="Bearer $token"
    Prefer="return=minimal"
}

$Data = Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $headers -Uri $Url -Method GET -ContentType "application/json"
```

Comment: Hello Vadim, but this is not working for POST method using the return=minimal header - comes out error like

Comment: {
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorInvalidIdMalformed",
    "message": "Id is malformed.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "4f508c38-217d-4673-8816-2bf046dfa357",
      "date": "2019-06-12T02:23:05"
    }
  }
}